# .htaccess redirect Home page to query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect

```
example.com/
```

to new path on same domain:

```
example.com/?viewr=UNESCO/$1
```

How can do it using `.htaccess`?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "domain.com/?viewr=UNESCO/$1" - is that `$1` literal text?

Comment: @MrWhite LIKE IT :: https://goo.zvendo.dev/?viewr=UNESCO/$1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect `example.com/` to `example.com/?viewr=UNESCO/$1` then you would need to use mod_rewrite in order to check the query string. Try the following at the top of root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^$ /?viewr=UNESCO/\$1 [R=302,L]
```

The literal `$` in the *substitution* string (2nd argument to the `RewriteRule` directive) needs to be backslash-escaped to prevent `$1` being interpreted as a backreference (which is *empty*).

---

**UPDATE:** If you are using this in a virtualhost context (ie. directly in the `<VirtualHost>` container, not inside a `<Directory>` container) then you will need to adjust the `RewriteRule` pattern from `^$` to `^/$`. In other words:

```
:
RewriteRule ^/$ /?viewr=UNESCO/\$1 [R=302,L]
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: I add it in.httaccess   and Vhost
And nothing has changed

Comment: @الفنونالقتاليةAhmedHosny Where in `.htaccess` have you placed this directive? Please edit your question include your complete `.htaccess` file with this directive in place. This rule as written won't work in a virtualhost context.

Comment: brother >> how make a redirect  to domain.com/?viewr=UNESCO  without $1

Comment: domain.com to new path on same domain >> domain.com/?viewr=UNESCO/

Comment: @الفنونالقتاليةAhmedHosny You would just remove the `/\$1` (or `\$1`) at the end of the _substitution_ string.